# kommen oder gehen (raus/rauf,runter..)

Tags: meaning

Liebe Experter,

verstehe ich die Verben kommen und gehen richtig?
Beispiele:

1. Peter ist im Haus. Marta ist draußen. Marta ruft Peter: "Komm raus!". Peter sagt "ok, ich gehe jetzt raus."
2. Peter ist im 1. Geschoss. Marta ist im 2. GEschoss. Marta ruft Pete "komm rauf!". Peter: "Ok, ich gehe jetzt rauf."
   Ebenfalls mit "rüber, rein"
3. Marta zu Peter: "komm rüber! " --> Peter: "später gehe ich rüber" (kann ich auch sagen: später komme ich rüber?
4. Marta zu Peter: "komm runter! " --> Peter: "später gehe ich runter" (kann ich auch sagen: später komme ich runter?

vielen Dank für eure Antwort

Answer (score 1):

All of those can be used in most of the cases, considering that Peter can answer from his own or from Marta's viewpoint.

If you change your example to a situation where Marta and Peter are in the same room and she wants him gone, she can *only* say:

> Bitte geh' raus

and he might answer

> Ich gehe jetzt raus

Comment: vielen Dank für deine Erklärung!